# jQuery + Fancybox: Get element of iframe's parent by jQuery notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have two Fancybox links which open their respective targets in Fancybox modal dialogs.

They are: "Login" and "Join" and they are both Fancybox iframes.

On the "Join" page, I need a link that says "If you're already a member, click *here* to login", which then needs to close the "Join" window and open up the "Login" window. Note that those two windows are of different sizes, which precludes me from simply using a good old fashioned link.

The current plan is as follows (JavaScript);

```
function openLogin() {
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    parent.$("#fancybox-login").click();
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work. I've messed around with it quite a bit, trying `$("parent.#fancybox-login")` and such, but to no avail.

Instead, the Fancybox window closes, and then it's as if the second line gets ignored.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

close - window.parent.$ should do the trick...

Comment: I don't follow. I need the element with the ID "fancybox-login", where does that fit in?